# rust-analyzer completion broken

Tags: lsp-mode, rust

When I try to use auto-completion with `lsp` + `rust-analyzer`, all functions inserted like that:

```
shared_state.clone_from(${1:source})$0
```

I cannot find any way to disable this "arguments". I don't even understand what package is inserting this (I use `prelude` bundle + `company`). Replacing `rust-analyzer` with `rls` as language server helps, at least it looks like:

```
shared_state.clone_from
```

when I hit "Enter", which is better, cuz I don't need to remove anything.

Any advise or help would be much appreciated, thx.

### Update 1

Okay, I looked at `lsp` log, and seems like this `(${1:source})$0` is raw response from `rust-analyzer`. So now I need to think a way to convert this representation to something, what, I suppose `company`, will be able to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, seems like I missed part that `yasnippet` should be enabled. `yas-minor-mode` fixed it.